# Elegant way to calculate the center of a Möbius circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Given the Möbius transform
$$ M(z) = \frac{z + 1 - i}{z + 1 +i} $$
I want to show that the image of the circle $|z| < 2$ contains the negative part of the real axis.

Intuitively I would calculate the image of the ring $|z| = 2$. Using software I found out that it is the circle of radius $2$ around $2 + i$. How can I elegantly show this in a pen and paper calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be real and non-negative.

Then solve $ -x = \dfrac{z + 1 - i}{z + 1 +i}$ for $z$ to get $z = -1 -\dfrac{x-1}{x+1} i$, and $z$ of this form are those sent to the negative real axis under this transformation,

but $-1 \le \dfrac{x-1}{x + 1} \lt 1$ for $x \ge 0$ so such $z$ has $1 \le |z| \le \sqrt{2}$, which is a subset of $|z| \lt 2$,

meaning that the image of the disk $|z| \lt 2$ contains the negative real axis.